# PHP count sub-directory levels in scandir loop

Tags: php, foreach, scandir

I got the following code that scans directory and outputs files and sub-folders in the following format:

```
file1.php
folder1
   file2.php
   folder2
       file3.php
file4.php
```

For my hyperlinks I need to refer to links with the number of levels. So for example: file1.php, folder1 and file4.php are all level number 1. file2.php, an folder2 is level 2, and file3.php is level 3.

Any advice on how I can use a loop counter to achieve this?

```
$directory = $_SERVER["DOCUMENT_ROOT"]."/files/";

function folderFleList($dir, $menu_class){
    $ffs = scandir($dir);
    echo "<ul class=\"".$menu_class."\">\n";
    foreach($ffs as $ff){
        if($ff != '.' && $ff != '..'){
            echo '<li class="menu-item"><a href="#" class="menu-link-level-1">'.$ff;
            if(is_dir($dir.'/'.$ff)) folderFleList($dir.'/'.$ff, "menu-sublist");
            echo '</a></li>';
        }
    }
    echo "</ul>\n";
}

folderFleList($directory, "menu-list");
```

Comment: Still unclear for me. What are you trying to get?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just add an extra parameter to your function:

```
function folderFleList($dir, $menu_class, $level = 1){
    $ffs = scandir($dir);
    echo "<ul class=\"".$menu_class."\">\n";
    foreach($ffs as $ff){
        if($ff != '.' && $ff != '..'){
            echo '<li class="menu-item">
                     <a href="#" class="menu-link-level-' . $level . '">'.$ff;
            if(is_dir($dir.'/'.$ff))
                folderFleList($dir.'/'.$ff, "menu-sublist", $level+1);
            echo '</a></li>';
        }
    }
    echo "</ul>\n";
}

folderFleList($directory, "menu-list");
```

Comment: in the href i currently have # but i would like to replace it with $ff which is the filename. However, this only shows the latest level of file. So for example it shows file3.php but in file3.php example it should really be /folder1/folder2/file3.php. Any ideas how i can do this?

Comment: You have *$dir*. If you remove *$_SERVER["DOCUMENT_ROOT"]* from it, I think you are close to what you need to prefix *$ff* with.